# $.contextMenu is not a function at HTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I want to implement [contextMenu Plugin](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu) but every time got error

> $.contextMenu is not a function     at HTMLDocument

I tried it like in the [demo](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-one',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
            },
            items: {
                "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
                "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
                copy: { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
                "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
                "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
                "sep1": "---------",
                "quit": {
                    name: "Quit", icon: function () {
                        return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function (e) {
            console.log('clicked', this);
        })
    });
</script>

<span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span>
```

I tried implement libraries by file:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
```

and by cdnjs:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
```

Nothing works.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/
You seem to have to target it at a specific element.

Comment: Your example with cdn is completely works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/extempl/1dr4tLe8/

Comment: Problem was solved by set up code outside of Jquery $(function () {}) . But my question is why now it works ?